# How do you upload a Mac app's icon to the new iTunes Connect

Tags: macos, icons, app-store-connect

I can upload screenshots to the new iTunes Connect for my Mac app, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to upload the icon.  All I get is this:

[image]

-Brian

Comment: Hey Brian! Cliff here from AP, having the same exact dang problem. I think it is supposed to pull it from your Binary... when I figure it out I'll let you know!

Answer (score 1):

New Mac Apps which have never yet been submitted for Review do not show an App Icon in the iTunes Connect portal until a binary has been uploaded AND you have actually submitted it for Review. Once submitted it pulls it from the binary and displays it on the dashboard.

[image]